# How to eliminate parameter of parametric equations?

Tags: parametric

If the parameter $t$ of $x$ and $y$ in a plane is given in the interval $(- ∞ , ∞)$ and if $x = t cos (t)$ and $y = t sin (t)$ How can one eliminate the parameter t and write a single equation using only $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Formatting hint: if you prefix the trigonometric functions' names with a backslash, LaTeX/MathJax will know they are functions' symbols and render them in upright font with appriopriate spacing: `t\sin x` → $t\sin x$, instead of a formless mass of italics: `t sin x` → $t sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Do we know something about $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$?

And how can we obtain that from the parametric equations given?

EDIT(Response to Q in comments):

Dividing the equations will help you eliminate the resulting $t$ in the last step.

Comment: I tried that and ended up with x² + y² = t²

Comment: Formatting hint: if you prefix the trigonometric functions' names with a backslash, LaTeX/MathJax will know they are functions' symbols and render them in upright font with appriopriate spacing: `t\sin x` → $t\sin x$, instead of a formless mass of italics: `t sin x` → $t sin x$.

Comment: Divide the 2 equations. $tan(t) = \frac{y}{x}$. Therefore $t= tan^{-1}(y/x)$. Substitute that in the above equation obtained.

Comment: @Vizag , Thanks that helped

Comment: Sure, no problem!